# Android browser ignoring CSS on HTML5 input tags

Tags: android, css, html

I'm working on a mobile version of a website and I really wanted to use the HTML5 input field types `number`, `email` and `tel`.  When I do this both Android and iOS show the keyboards I want them to when the user has those fields selected, but in Android the CSS attributes for the fields are ignored now that I changed it from `type="text"`, specifically the CSS `width` attribute.

I updated my CSS file to make sure the values for `input[type="text"]` also applied to `input[type="email"]` etc.. and this works great on iOS.  Is there some trick to get the Android browser to pick up CSS attributes on the new HTML5 input field types?

I'm testing on a Droid X running Android 2.2 with the default Android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the CSS parser does not recognize the selector and skips it. Try setting an id on it. And applying the CSS to the id.

==EXAMPLE==

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="foo" />
```

CSS:

```
input#foo
{
    width: 100%; //OR WHATEVER
}
```

Comment: I created a very stripped down page to test this and it works.  Apparently I've got something strange going on in the CSS of the page that is giving me trouble because it doesn't work there.  This helped me get around the problem though.  Thanks.